# Js file not loaded after partial view is refreshed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the simple partial view:

```
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label- primary">@Model.AverageRaiting.ToString("# stars")</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new {id = @Model.PhotoId}), "Update Photo", Url.Action("Photo"))
    @Html.Action("InitializeAlerts")
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/reload.alerts.js"></script>
}
```

Everything is ok by the first time. But after I replace the partial view by another one like above the custom script `"reload.alerts.js"` doesn't work. This script is for `@Html.Action("InitializeAlerts")` action.
`InitializeAlerts` method just return a partial view named _Alert.
What shall I do to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the script in your main view and not in partial view?

Comment: @Alorika yes. To be sure it is not because of this I've included it in both views.

Comment: Can you post your code from reaload.alerts.js and _Alert partial view. Maybe you have problem with dynamical binding in partial view.

Comment: @freshbm I created a new question for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `@section scripts` in Partial Views.

Everything works fine if you render it in Main View becouse Razor knows where to put your script on `_Layout` but when you refresh if you basically make ajax call and you get row html.

Since you get only Partial page without `_Layout` Razor just cut this line so your script link doesn't even came to client.

You have 2 options:

1. like @Alorika said you should place your script in main View. But there could be problems and it depends on what your script do and how it do it. That's good practice and i recommend to use it. If script doesn't work you should look at it where it falls.
2. Delete `@section scripts` and put your script link without it. I'm not sure, but i suspect that there is some possibilities when your script won't work this way either depending on how you write it.

Comment: Thanks! It works if I delete the section. As you say it is bad practice. So, how to update the js file to make it works from main view?

Comment: @user3818229 I gess it's better to ask another question where you put your script and all the details.

Comment: Yes, sure!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451210/the-js-file-doesnt-work-in-partial-view-after-it-refreshed