# The JS file doesn't work in partial view after it refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is branch question of "[Js file not loaded after partial view is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450795/js-file-not-loaded-after-partial-view-is-refreshed/34450945?noredirect=1#comment56643493_34450945)".
The broblem is that if I put my script in to the main view it doesn't work in partial.
My custom script:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1000).slideUp(1000, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 3000);
    $("[data-hide]").on("click", function () {
        if (timer != null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The Photo partial view where I need to use my script:

```
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.AverageRaiting.ToString("# stars")</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new {id = @Model.PhotoId}), "Update Photo", Url.Action("Photo"))
    @Html.Action("InitializeAlerts")
</div>
```

And partail view "_Alert" which rendering in to the partial where I need to use the script above:

```
@{
    var alerts = TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey)
                ? (List<Alert>)TempData[Alert.TempDataKey]
                : new List<Alert>();

    if (alerts.Any())
    {
        <hr />
    }
    foreach (var alert in alerts)
    {
        var dismissableClass = alert.Dismissable? "alert-dismissable" : null;
        <div class="alert alert-@alert.AlertStyle fade in @dismissableClass">
            @if (alert.Dismissable)
            {
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</button>
            }
            @Html.Raw(alert.Message)
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the script in your main layout, not in a partial. Then use the delegated event handler shown. This should work on all partial views.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Right now I put it in main view of partial photo. I think it is bad to load it in layout if I don't need this script in another views.

Comment: Once loaded the overhead is the same whether you use it or not. It is a very tiny script. Just load it in main, once, and don't make life harder for yourself :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks for good advice but could you explain why it doesn't work if I place it in the Main Photo View?

Comment: Sure: If you please explain what your Main Photo view is... Is it a partial, is it a full view? How is it loaded? Is it the one shown above (which is not named)? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It even doesn't work from layout:( I guess the problem still in the script.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is possibly the least useful statement you can make. I use this technique with 30 plugins and 1000s of lines of JS code every day, so you need to provide a bit more the go on :) Please provide a dump of the page saved from a browser, e.g. in a JSFiddle and post a link. Easier to spot what other issues there may be then.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm a beginner in jquery and don't speak English well sometimes I don't know how to explain clearly. Let me show Main Photo View.

Comment: Just trying to get at the real problems. Please do show a entire page as requested as that is much easier than looking at tiny pieces of the puzzle. Thanks :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie By the way it work's if I manually put the script without script section in partial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98907/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-user3818229).

Comment: If you put the script inline in a partial, be very careful. If you do it that way (not recommended), *do not* use a delegated handler or you could wind up with multiple handlers firing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', "[data-hide]", function ()
```

The jQuery selector is only run *at event time,* so it will work with dynamically added elements.

It works by listening for the event at a non-changing ancestor element (document is the safest default if nothing else is closer/convenient). It then applies the selector to the elements in the bubble-chain. It then applies your event handler function to only the matching elements that caused the event.

This is very efficient compared to connecting event handlers to individual elements and any speed difference is negligible as you simply cannot click fast enough to notice :)

Comment: Probably I need to add something like you wrote to automatic hide function?

Comment: @user3818229: Eh? Please explain what you mean? Simply replace your current event handler with the example shown.

Comment: I did it but my timer isn't executed.

Comment: Where is your script? Please ensure your example shows all code so we can spot any other issues :) A simply way is to save the entire page from the browser (not source) so a mockup can be made in a JSFiddle etc

Answer (score 1):

This happens as you have removed the DOM elements that jQuery attached its events to. jQuery doesn't keep track of the page and add new events when you add new elements, its a one time deal.  You can get around this by placing the event on a parent that always exists on the page and then use a selector to get at the elements you want. The jQuery documentation for the .on() method tells you more.

I need to modify code as follows:(working well if partial view refreshed)

```
var item_to_delete;
    $("#serviceCharge").on('click','.deleteItem' ,function (e) {
        item_to_delete = $(this).data('id');
        alert(item_to_delete);
    });
```

My Previous code was: (working till partial view not refresh)

```
var item_to_delete;
        $(".deleteItem").click(function (e) {
            item_to_delete = $(this).data('id');
        });
```