# My Javascript code doesn't run inside my MVC view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some issues implementing this template into my MVC application.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid

My CSS and code works fine, but the Javascript doesn't work.

I'm using a partial view to contain the code which looks like this:

```
@model List<Assignment_3.Models.Word>

<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ResponsiveGrid.js")'></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <section id="pinBoot">
                @foreach (var word in Model)
                {
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <article class="white-panel">

                            <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", new { id = Word.WordId })">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(Idiom.Imagepath)" />
                            </a>
                            <h4 class="textwrapper">Test</h4>
                            <p>Language</p>
                        </article>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                }
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    body {
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    .textwrapper {
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    #pinBoot {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .white-panel {
        position: absolute;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .white-panel h1 {
            font-size: 1em;
    }

    .white-panel h1 a {
            color: #A92733;
    }

    .white-panel:hover {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            margin-top: -5px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#pinBoot').pinterest_grid({
    no_columns: 4,
    padding_x: 10,
    padding_y: 10,
    margin_bottom: 50,
    single_column_breakpoint: 700
});
});

usage:

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#blog-landing').pinterest_grid({
    no_columns: 4
});
});

; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
var pluginName = 'pinterest_grid',
    defaults = {
        padding_x: 10,
        padding_y: 10,
        no_columns: 3,
        margin_bottom: 50,
        single_column_breakpoint: 700
    },
    columns,
    $article,
    article_width;

function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    var self = this,
        resize_finish;

    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(resize_finish);
        resize_finish = setTimeout(function () {
            self.make_layout_change(self);
        }, 11);
    });

    self.make_layout_change(self);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(window).resize();
    }, 500);
};

Plugin.prototype.calculate = function (single_column_mode) {
    var self = this,
        tallest = 0,
        row = 0,
        $container = $(this.element),
        container_width = $container.width();
    $article = $(this.element).children();

    if (single_column_mode === true) {
        article_width = $container.width() - self.options.padding_x;
    } else {
        article_width = ($container.width() - self.options.padding_x * 
self.options.no_columns) / self.options.no_columns;
    }

    $article.each(function () {
        $(this).css('width', article_width);
    });

    columns = self.options.no_columns;

    $article.each(function (index) {
        var current_column,
            left_out = 0,
            top = 0,
            $this = $(this),
            prevAll = $this.prevAll(),
            tallest = 0;

        if (single_column_mode === false) {
            current_column = (index % columns);
        } else {
            current_column = 0;
        }

        for (var t = 0; t < columns; t++) {
            $this.removeClass('c' + t);
        }

        if (index % columns === 0) {
            row++;
        }

        $this.addClass('c' + current_column);
        $this.addClass('r' + row);

        prevAll.each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('c' + current_column)) {
                top += $(this).outerHeight() + self.options.padding_y;
            }
        });

        if (single_column_mode === true) {
            left_out = 0;
        } else {
            left_out = (index % columns) * (article_width + 
self.options.padding_x);
        }

        $this.css({
            'left': left_out,
            'top': top
        });
    });

    this.tallest($container);
    $(window).resize();
};

Plugin.prototype.tallest = function (_container) {
    var column_heights = [],
        largest = 0;

    for (var z = 0; z < columns; z++) {
        var temp_height = 0;
        _container.find('.c' + z).each(function () {
            temp_height += $(this).outerHeight();
        });
        column_heights[z] = temp_height;
    }

    largest = Math.max.apply(Math, column_heights);
    _container.css('height', largest + (this.options.padding_y + 
this.options.margin_bottom));
};

Plugin.prototype.make_layout_change = function (_self) {
    if ($(window).width() < _self.options.single_column_breakpoint) {
        _self.calculate(true);
    } else {
        _self.calculate(false);
    }
};

$.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin(this, options));
        }
    });
}

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Any tips in getting the Javascript to work would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Place the script in your main layout, not in a partial. Then use the delegated event handler shown. This should work on all partial views

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you kindly elaborate on the event handler?Where might I find this in the code above?

Comment: See this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451210/the-js-file-doesnt-work-in-partial-view-after-it-refreshed

Comment: Thanks for this, and I have looked into it. However, now I think that there is actually an issue with the JS code itself as I've moved everything from the partial page and still can't get it to work. When I debug in Chrome, I notice an error that says, "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pinterest_grid is not a function" - any idea what that could refer to?

Comment: Usually means that either you haven't put JQuery lib at first or that you have a typo on your function, and It seems is your first function so that's highly probably. As a side note check that you already have the `pinterest_grid` plugin/script

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to have your javascript files right before the closing body tag even though you are using jQuery and other open source libraries. Have you inspected the browser(F12 on windows) to see if the URL that you are pointing to is loading the file on the network? In MVC, you might want to put the JS file inside of bundle.config and referencing them using Bundling and Minification like the following

**In Bundle.config**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/script.js");
```

**In Application_Start Event**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
protected void Application_Start()
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
}
```

and 
**On the UI**

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
```

This way , your  JS files are minified and changes are always reflected onto the UI(Solves caching issues)

Comment: Thank you Sudeep, though I've tested this and am afraid it's not related to the bundles. I am now testing all of the code, including script, in the same view and still can't get it to work. When I debug on the Javascript, I receive a "Breakpoint will not currently be hit" error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the output html in your browser, you'll see that the url in your script tag probably doesn't resolve correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ResponsiveGrid.js")'>
</script>
```

You can fix this by using a url relative to the root of the domain.

```
src="/Scripts/ResponsiveGrid.js"
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I've tested this there was no problem here. I am now testing all of the code, including <script></script>, in the same view and still can't get it to work. When I debug on the Javascript, I receive a "Breakpoint will not currently be hit" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding "debugger;" at the start of your js code to ensure your not hitting it.